# Multi-page text report with BIRT

Tags: java, report, birt

I have a report which I need to create with BIRT which is simply two large sections of text. The text will come in from XML, so I could use an XML datasource to load the text, but how do I just create a text section which could span multiple pages, I'm not using tabular data or anything like that.

Comment: What you're trying to do is to split your text on different pages ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have an XML source with two elements, each containing a large section of text, you can use the XML data source or the Scripted Data Source. Drop the Data Set into a table, and set the page break on the Detail row to 1 row and always. This will break up the two large text elements into separate pages.

Answer (score 1):

No special measures should be required for a text section to split over multiple pages - this will happen automatically, if the field is large enough to require paging.

Answer (score -1):

Something to note when having dynamic text span multiple pages:

The report layout should be set to "Auto Layout", otherwise it duplicates the text over multiple pages. This is only applicable when using the report viewer.

No good if you want to use fixed layout for a report.